# readlink -f doesn't work as expected

Tags: shell-script, scripting, readlink

This is a script I'm writing for exercise. 
It should recursively find all regular files in the current directory's subtree and change the last modification date to yesterday date.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                
YESTERDAY=$(date -d yesterday)                             

RFILES=$(ls -lR | egrep '^-' | rev | cut -d" " -f1 | rev)  

for i in $RFILES ; do                                      
   ABSPATH=$(readlink -f $i)                               
   touch "$ABSPATH" -d "$YESTERDAY"                       
done
```

If I call it in a directory with a subtree like the following:

```
a  
|___ b  
|    |__ file1  
|    |__ file2
|    
|__ file3  
|__ file4
```

`readlink` doesn't work as expected. What I mean is that it tells me that `file1` and `file2` are inside the directory `a`. So when I use `touch` to change theirs last modification date it creates two more `file1` and `file2` in the `a` directory with the date of yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, command `ls -lR | egrep '^-' | rev | cut -d" " -f1 | rev` just shows file names without paths. If you need get all files with paths you can use `find ./ -type f` and parse that output. Therefore `readlink -f $i` command will not be necessary.

Secondly, if you need more effective solution, you need only `find` command with `exec` parameter:

```
find . -type f -exec touch -d "$YESTERDAY" {} +

-type f       find regular files
```

Comment: @Kusalananda Of course. Firstly I posted in right order but after I've changed it because I saw another answer and thought that I have a typo. Now, I remember it. I fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The readlink program is for reading the location of symbolic links, if you just have regular files there may be better tools for the job.  For finding files, I like to use the `find` command.  It appears you can do your whole exercise in one step using find:

```
find . -type f -exec touch {} -d "$(date -d yesterday)" \;
```

- `find .`: search the current directory `.`, and everything underneath
- `-type f`: search only for regular files
- `-exec`: tell find to run the following command for each object it finds
- `touch {} -d "$(date -d yesterday)" \;`: the command you want to perform on each file.  The "{}" is the placeholder for the output of `find` and the \; designates the end of the `-exec` statement

Comment: With some implementations of `touch`, `touch filename -d date` will create the three files `filename`, `-d` and `date`.  Ideally, you will want to have the options first, _then_ the filename(s). GNU utilities don't seem to care, but every other set of utilities do.

Answer (score 0):

Your RFILES are just file names without paths. `readlink` isn't `find`, it uses the names you give it, and without a path in them, they are assumed to be in the current directory.

With modern bash:

```
shopt -s globstar
RFILES=( ** )
```

But you don't need `readlink` you can use the output of `ls` directly. With `globstar` it's as simple as:

```
touch -d "$YESTERDAY" $(ls -d **)
```

and in practice you don't even need `ls`:

```
touch -d "$YESTERDAY" **
```

Otherwise with `find`:

```
find . -type f -exec touch -d "$YESTERDAY" {} +
```

Finallly, the date specification to `touch` is more flexible than you think:

```
touch -d yesterday **
```

will work...

Comment: Even better than `$(ls **)` is: `**`

Comment: Right :) Fixed it